# Is Github languages dropdown broken for individual repositories?

Tags: github

See screenshot, the Language dropdown only shows 'All` for individual repos.
[image]
There was a time (around Jan / Feb 2020 and prior ?) when I am pretty sure I could see other prog languages, e.g. C#, Javascript, etc.. as dropdown values.

For "organization" repos, e.g. Microsoft, the dropdown shows other languages (still functioning as it should, no change here).

What's going on, was there an update to the github website ?

Comment: I just checked my personal github and my Language dropdown is functioning properly. All options I expect are there and the filtering works as well.

Comment: that is very strange.. my problem is exactly as described in the question. Try https://github.com/jskeet?tab=repositories, for me i can only see `All`

Comment: you are correct, I only see `All` there. Something I noticed...if I log out and look at my repos, I only see `All` but when I log in, the dropdown is correct and has all my languages. But only on mine, not on Jon's or anywhere else. I wonder if there is a setting somewhere that was added...